# Deleting lines in VisPy

Tags: vispy

How can one delete visuals(e.g. lines) from a PlotWidget?

I have tried explicitly removing a Line from everywhere the PlotWidget adds the Line object when you call plot(), but this does not change anything on the displayed canvas.

Answer (score 3):

Set its parent to None:

`line_obj.parent = None`